# SharePoint Online CSOM Site Column Default Value

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

In SharePoint Online, I'm having problems setting a site Managed Metadata column default value using CSOM (C#). For brevity, I've not included exception handling in my code. Here's what I have:

```
// Code snippet for what I'm trying to achieve
using (ClientContext ctx = NewCtx(SiteInfo.Url)) // NewCtx is just a static member I use to return a ClientContext object
{
  Field taxColumn = (Field)ctx.Web.Fields.GetByTitle("myMMColumnName");
  ctx.Load(taxColumn);
  ctx.ExecuteQuery();
  TaxonomyFieldValue termField = new TaxonomyFieldValue();
  termField.Label = "My MM Term";
  termField.TermGuid = "b269aef7-6f47-4b02-bf80-7edfb7166a30";
  termField.WssId = -1;
  taxColumn.DefaultValue = value;
  // Place holder for added code (see below)
  taxColumn.Update();
  ctx.Load(taxColumn);
  ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

The value appears in the UI under Site Columns, but no associated item is created in the TaxonomyHiddenList, which makes sense because setting the lookup WssId to "-1" doesn't resolve and therefore, the default value doesn't have a lookup and appears empty in the list- and library-level column.

The closest resolution I found was an article (albeit not CSOM and linked below) suggested creating a "dummy" list item (against a list that was consuming the MM column). This would trigger the creation of the item in the TaxonomyHiddenList but the article suggests not committing the "dummy" item creation. I've tried this too, but seems to have no effect. This is the code I added to the place holder mentioned in the previous code block:

```
List myList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("My List");
ctx.Load(myList);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
TaxonomyField taxField = ctx.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(myList.Fields.GetByTitle("myMMColumnName"));
ListItemCreationInformation newItemInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
ListItem newItem = myList.AddItem(newItemInfo);
newItem["myMMColumnName"] = termField;
taxField.SetFieldValueByValue(newItem, termField);
```

The article uses the .SetFieldValue method, which isn't available in CSOM so I may well have assumed incorrectly that .SetFieldValueByValue is comparable.

Thanks for reading!

References:
Article - http://sharepointificate.blogspot.com/2014/04/setting-managed-metadata-column-default.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SetFieldValue Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfield.setfieldvalue(v=office.14).aspx) belongs to `TaxonomyField` class, it means the line:

```
Field taxColumn = (Field)ctx.Web.Fields.GetByTitle(taxFieldTitle);
```

needs to be replaced with:

```
var taxColumn = ctx.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(ctx.Web.Fields.GetByTitle(taxFieldTitle));
```

or

```
TaxonomyField taxColumn = ctx.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(ctx.Web.Fields.GetByTitle(taxFieldTitle));
```

Once `TaxonomyField` is initialized, the default value could be set as shown below:

```
//get taxonomy field
var taxColumn = ctx.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(ctx.Web.Fields.GetByTitle(taxFieldTitle));
ctx.Load(taxColumn);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
//initialize taxonomy field value
var defaultValue = new TaxonomyFieldValue();
defaultValue.WssId = -1;
defaultValue.Label = termLabel;
defaultValue.TermGuid = termId.ToString();
//retrieve validated taxonomy field value
var validatedValue = taxColumn.GetValidatedString(defaultValue);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
//set default value for a taxonomy field
taxColumn.DefaultValue = validatedValue.Value;
taxColumn.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

> Note: [`TaxonomyField.GetValidatedString method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfield.getvalidatedstring.aspx) is utilized for
>   validation of taxonomy field value which in turn includes the
>   resolving of `WssId` value

**Update**

Use [`Field.UpdateAndPushChanges method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.field.updateandpushchanges.aspx) to propagate changesto all lists that use the field

So, replace:

```
taxColumn.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

with:

```
taxColumn.UpdateAndPushChanges(true);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Hi Vadim. That's a great response and thank you for also explaining what I was missing. I can now see the associated item in the TaxonomyHiddenList and the site columns look fine, however when I create a new item in a list that inherits the site column, the default value is still blank. Do I need to implement this against the lists / libraries too?

Comment: You probably need to replace method  `Update` with  `UpdateAndPushChanges`.  For a more details follow the updated answer (Update section)